# django and javascript how to organize

Tags: javascript, django, variables, embed

I'm trying to figure out how to organize my javascript/django code.

So far I used to put my javascript page specific code in the same file. i.e I embed javascript in a `<script>` tag inside the template.
This creates a lot of mess when my JS code become large:
- django template variables `{{var}}` inside my JS code does not look well,
- I get an error when I try to minify it with tools like this one: http://jscompress.com/ ,
- And I just try to separate them as much as possible.

Today, in my embeded `<script>` tag my JS code looks like:

```
var app = {
  func: function() {
    // can I use the {% url %} tag here ?
    $.post('/url/', {csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}', something:'value'} )

  },
  jsonFromServer: '{{pythonDict|safe}}', // I need this data structure,
};
```

As you can see, there are some values I need to pass form django to javascript, the most common is the csrftoken, for ajax requests. But sometimes I also pass a json dictionary that is needed for the app itself. Sometimes I want to pass the server time as well.

I'm thinking of moving the JS code to a separate file, I read that it is better way to organize like that. But I can't see how it is possible in a normal django app, without django have  to render the .js files. And I believe it is better the JS file won't be served by django?
So how could I organize my JS without too much django code in it ?

Answer (score 0):

I Don't know if it's "beautiful" but usually, I organize my code like that when it's about make web dev in MVC:

- I put my <script> tag in the template of my page.
- I write my js in an external file, traditionally in the /static/JS/my_template_name.js
- As my gobal layout can have some JS code too, I make a great use of the JS modules: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc#.bjf4xwuq4

Comment: Still dont understand how you pass django variables to the JS code in your external file. Do you set them in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I don't have to do that. 
When I need var from server in my js code, I make some Ajax calls.

But if you really want to process like that, I can suggest you to do something like this in your template:

```
<script>
     var from_server = {{vars_from_server}};
</script>
```

Normally, if you pass a variable named vars_from_server to your template it will replace the placeholder between the script tags. Just think to format "vars_from_server" in a correct JS way.

After that, you will be able to access your vars in your scripts by accessing from_server variable from anywhere.

Comment: And what about the url template tag in javascript, i.e ajax request? Today I use it in JS, but I cant minify the code as I said..